# jdbc - java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I know that there are many topics out there, with similar questions, however none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

I'm using `MAMP` and I'm trying to connect to a -already existing- database using java with the following code:

```
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "root";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Class not found");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            System.out.println("Instantiation exception");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            System.out.println("Illegal access exception");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } // catch

        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to the database..");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass); 
            System.out.println("Successfully connected to the database");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Unable to connect to the database");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } // catch
```

When the code is executed I get the following exception:

```
Unable to connect to the database
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2336)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at registrationsystem.SignUpForm.submitJButtonActionPerformed(SignUpForm.java:293)
    at registrationsystem.SignUpForm.access$000(SignUpForm.java:19)
    at registrationsystem.SignUpForm$1.actionPerformed(SignUpForm.java:94)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

What I've tried so far for fixing the problem:

1) Executed `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

2) Tried to create another user (instead of using root), but without any luck

3) When I run MAMP, port `3306`, user `root` and password `root` are specified, so I think that I'm not using a wrong password or port.

4) I have tried to connect using

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?user=root&password=root");
```

Comment: This error is most likely terminated at mysql end. Check your table user in database mysql for host / user combinations

Comment: @Jan can you please be more specific?

Comment: Nothing specific - it's just that everytime I've seen that issue it was due to bad authentication in mysql or wrong password given in Java. You should try to `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.*`  with correct db name as well,

Comment: Not sure if this is a possible problem but when I try to execute `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON information_schema.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION` in phpmyadmin, I get `#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'`

Comment: Could you run (and show) `show grants FOR 'root'@'localhost';`

Comment: Output can be better viewed here: http://postimg.org/image/yn54oseoz/ 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' ...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'mysql'.* TO 'root'@'local...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'project'.* TO 'root'@'loc...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'perfromance_schema'.* TO ...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'project'.'project' TO 'ro...
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GR...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96357/discussion-between-jan-and-old-school).